# Ускорение кода на Python

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Как можно ускорить?

```
a=input()
aa=[int(s) for s in input().split()]
b=input()
bb=[int(s) for s in input().split()]
c=input()
cc=[int(s) for s in input().split()]
sum=0
for i in aa:
    if i in bb and i in cc:
        sum+=1
print(sum)
```

Comment: Это вопрос по метке [инспекция-кода]. Должен содержать только работающий код. Если у вас вопрос "почему не работает" — не ставьте эту метку. Обязательно опишите реализуемую функциональность и назначение кода. Используйте стандартный для языка стиль кодирования — имена функций и переменных, отступы, пробелы и прочее. Подробная инструкция есть в полном описании. Посмотрите описание метки [инспекция-кода]

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь множествами.

Пример:

```
aa = [1, 3, 1, 5, 7, 9]    
bb = [1,2,3,4]    
cc = [1,3,10]

chk = set(bb) & set(cc)    
print(chk)
#{1, 3}

res = sum(x in chk for x in aa)    
print(res)
#3
```

---

Средняя сложность проверки `x in set` - `O(1)`, тогда как сложность проверки `x in list` - `O(n)`.

**Сравнение скорости выполнения для массивов, состоящих из 10.000 элементов:**

```
In [3]: %paste
from random import randint

N = 10**4
aa = [randint(0,1000) for _ in range(N)]
bb = [randint(0,10**7) for _ in range(N)]
cc = [randint(0,10**9) for _ in range(N)]
## -- End pasted text --

In [4]: %paste
%%timeit
sm=0
for i in aa:
    if i in bb and i in cc:
        sm+=1
## -- End pasted text --
3.74 s ± 46.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [5]: %paste
%%timeit
chk = set(bb) & set(cc)
res = sum(x in chk for x in aa)
## -- End pasted text --
5.16 ms ± 33.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

разница в скорости:

```
In [6]: 3.74 * 1000 / 5.16
Out[6]: 724.8062015503875
```